# Copy innerHTML of an iframe within another iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I stumbled a website like this, let's call it `home.html`

```
<body>
<iframe id='id1' src="1.html">
</iframe>
</body>
```

In `1.html`, we got

```
<body>...
<iframe id='id2' src="2.html">
</iframe>
...
</body>
```

How can I get the HTML content of `2.html` with JavaScript? The reason I do not go directly to `2.html` to get the content is because the content is simply a template and get changed dynamically at the `home.html`

Usually, i would just do like below to get the content of an iframe id but it doesn't work in this case.

```
var e = document.getElementById('myid').html;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are all of these iframes on the same domain?

Comment: Tried document.frames[0].frames[0].getElementById('myid')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
var iFrame =  document.getElementById('id1');
var iFrameBody= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
content= iFrameBody.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
alert(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

your iframes src should be same to your main page domain. Different domain content access is blocked by browsers. Same domain iframe contents can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to copy just BODY tag content between iframes, but you need to copy HEAD tag content as well to get the same design of new iframe

```
var iFrameDocument= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
alert(iFrameDocument.head.innerHTML);
alert(iFrameDocument.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the body with his **properties** you can now do :

```
iframe1.contentWindow.document.body = iframe2.contentWindow.document.body.cloneNode(true);
```

*cloneNode(true)* will copy every child of the specified node